# Prevent closing Modal from ASP NET Button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

For my **ASP Webforms Application** I use a **Modal from Bootstrap** for the settings.

```
<asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" OnClientClick="return false;" runat="server" Text="Einstellungen" />
```

As you can see, I already have to prevent the Button for postback. Because if I **click the button the Modal opens, postback starts and the Modal close.**

So this problem I fixed.

But now if I open the modal and wanna click a Button in this Modal:

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="dropbox" Text="Mit Dropbox anmelden" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="dropboxButton" CssClass="btn btn-info" />
```

The Modal close... But I want that the user sees that the Accountinformation from him filled in. 
Also I have a field for adding entries after clicking the "+" Button. After every click for adding, the modal will be closed...

I already tried **data-backdrop="static"** and something with Javascript and **e.preventDefault();**

Any ideas?

Comment: One work-around I have found, cause I have had similar problems with submit buttons, despite all precautions not to submit, is to use LinkButton. The signature is similar so just change it to LinkButton and try again.

Comment: <a class="btn btn-info" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl09','')">Mit Dropbox anmelden</a> this is the convert from asp net in html... so again a postback so that the modal closed...

Comment: After the clarifications, I believe you have entirely different problem from what I was trying to suggest. Sorry, hope you have worked it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking a server side ASP.NET Button control will cause a PostBack and your page will be re-loaded, therefore the modal will be closed.What you can do is call the code below in the click event to re-open the modal **after** the click event:

**Code behind:**

```
protected void btnClickMe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblTest.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy - HH:mm:ss");
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showModal();", true);
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showModal() {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }

        $(function () {
            $("#btnShowModal").click(function () {
                showModal();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="button" id="btnShowModal" value="Show Modal" />
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade"">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal popup</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnClickMe" runat="server" Text="Click Me" OnClick="btnClickMe_Click" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: thats it! Ok the modal shortly close and open for a second but its ok. thanks!

Comment: If you don't want the modal to close and open after the PostBack you could write an $ajax function in jQuery to  call a [WebMethod] in the code behind.That way the modal will stay completely open

Comment: Or the easiest way: just delete the fade transition in the ASPX file

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying this

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSpareRequisition" CssClass="btn  btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Request Spare" ClientIDMode="Static" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#requestSpareModalId" OnClientClick="return  false"/>
```

Here is my complete code

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
 <%-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>--%>
 <asp:Button ID="btnSpareRequisition" CssClass="btn  btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Request Spare" ClientIDMode="Static" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" OnClientClick="return  false" />
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: doesnt work for me... after clicking the Button it open and close... cause postback (reload content)

Comment: **OnClientClick="return  false"** added .Now try  @PeterH

Comment: yeah it works, but i already fixed this problem:  My main problem is if the Modal is open the Buttons inside the Modal close the modal cause postback i think... i want to know how to prevent closing the Modal after i click a button **inside** a modal.